# TikZ labelling venn diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

I have a 3-circle venn diagram

```
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (2cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(55:2.67cm) circle (2cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(0:3cm) circle (2cm)}

% Now we can draw the sets:
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw \firstcircle node[below] {$A$};
    \draw \secondcircle node [above] {$B$};
    \draw \thirdcircle node [below] {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How do I add text labels where the circles overlap?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

A simple solution is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{venn circle/.style={draw,circle,minimum width=6cm,fill=#1,opacity=0.4}}

  \node [venn circle = red] (A) at (0,0) {$A$};
  \node [venn circle = blue] (B) at (60:4cm) {$B$};
  \node [venn circle = green] (C) at (0:4cm) {$C$};
  \node[left] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,B=1/2 ) {$A \cap B$}; 
  \node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,C=1/2 ) {$A \cap C$};   
  \node[right] at (barycentric cs:B=1/2,C=1/2 ) {$B \cap C$};   
  \node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/3,B=1/3,C=1/3 ){$A \cap B \cap C$};
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice use of barycentric coordinates.  You could even handle circles of different radii by using appropriate factors in the coordinate specification.

Comment: Yes you are right but I made this solution very quickly without  flourish . There is a little problem with the names of the first circles and opacity.

Comment: It's important to note that you cannot use spacesin the barycentric coordinate specifications (like `A = 1/2`).  This is noted in section 13.2.2 of the TikZ manual, but it wouldn't be obvious to someone adapting the code from this answer.  Adding the spaces leads to an error.

Comment: It would have been nice to have an option to control/scale the size of the circles.

Comment: If someone wants the consistent label format without `A,B,C` influenced by `opacity`, we can use [`text opacity=1`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305529/308105).

Comment: @Curious It is controlled by `minimum width=6cm` in the answer although we can use other methods.

Answer (score 14):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}   
\SpecialCoor

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=0pt\relax
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3.25,-3.25)(3.25,3.25)
  \def\R{1}
  \def\RR{2}    
  \pnode(\R;30){A}\rput(\RR;30){$A$}
  \pnode(\R;150){B}\rput(\RR;150){$B$}
  \pnode(\R;270){C}\rput(\RR;270){$C$}
  \psset{opacity=0.4}
  \def\r{2}
  \pscircle*[linecolor=red](A){\r} 
  \pscircle*[linecolor=green](B){\r} 
  \pscircle*[linecolor=blue](C){\r}
  \def\d{1.5}
  \rput(\d;90){$A \cap B$}
  \rput(\d;210){$B \cap C$}
  \rput(\d;-30){$A \cap C$}  
  \rput(0,0){$A\cap B\cap C$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

You could place the labels manually by using `\node at (<x>,<y>) {$A \cap C$};`, but you'd have to find the coordinates by trial and error.

A more "proper" way is using the `intersections` library. To use it, you name the paths you want to intersect using unique names (`name path=<name>`), in this case the circles.

Then you can find the intersections by issuing `name intersections = {of=<firstpath> and <secondpath>}` as an argument to a `path` or a `draw` command.

The intersections will be available as coordinate nodes with the naming scheme `intersection-<number>`. You can now define a path between two intersections, and place a node halfway between the intersections using `node [pos=0.5] {<label>}` in the `path`.

For labelling the central overlap, you could use the `calc` library to specify the average of the circle coordinates using `($0.33*(A)+0.33*(B)+0.33*(C)$)`:

[image: venn diagrams label]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}

\def\firstcircle{[name path=firstcircle] (0,0) circle (2cm)}
\def\secondcircle{[name path=secondcircle] (55:2.67cm) circle (2cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{[name path=thirdcircle] (0:3cm) circle (2cm)}

% Now we can draw the sets:
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw \firstcircle node[below,name=A] {$A$};
    \draw \secondcircle node [above,name=B] {$B$};
    \draw \thirdcircle node [below,name=C] {$C$};
    \path [ name intersections = {of = firstcircle and secondcircle } ] (intersection-1) -- (intersection-2) node [pos=0.5] {$A \cap B$};
    \path [ name intersections = {of = secondcircle and thirdcircle } ] (intersection-1) -- (intersection-2) node [pos=0.5] {$B \cap C$};
    \path [ name intersections = {of = firstcircle and thirdcircle } ] (intersection-1) -- (intersection-2) node [pos=0.5] {$A \cap C$};
    \node at ($0.33*(B)+0.33*(C)+0.33*(A)$) {$A \cap B \cap C$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, how about where the three overlap?

Comment: If you're using the calc library to get the threefold overlap, you might as well do it for the others.  The A interect B label can go at $0.5*(A) + 0.5*(B)$, etc.

Comment: Also, do you have a solution that would accommodate circles of different sizes?  For instance, if you change the size of circle A to 3cm, the label for B is in B intersect C, and the label for B intersect C is in A intersect B intersect C.

Answer (score 8):

Run it with `XeLaTeX`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}    
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(5,4)
  \psnode(0,0){first}{A}\psnode(2.67;55){second}{B}\psnode(3,0){third}{C}
  \pscircle*[linecolor=red,opacity=0.4](first){2} 
  \pscircle*[linecolor=green,opacity=0.4](second){2} 
  \pscircle*[linecolor=blue,opacity=0.4](third){2}
  \ncline[linestyle=none]{first}{second}\ncput{$A \cap B$}
  \ncline[linestyle=none]{first}{third}\ncput{\rnode{AC}{$A \cap C$}}
  \ncline[linestyle=none]{second}{third}\ncput{$B \cap C$}
  \ncline[linestyle=none]{second}{AC}\ncput[npos=0.75]{$A\cap B\cap C$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, how about where the three overlap?

Comment: see edited answer

Answer (score 6):

For anyone looking for something simple, consider using the  `venndiagram` package (which depends on TikZ):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{venndiagram}

\begin{document}

\begin{venndiagram3sets}[labelOnlyAB={$A \cap B$},
                         labelOnlyAC={$A \cap C$},
                         labelOnlyBC={$B \cap C$},
                         labelABC={$A \cap B \cap C$},
                         radius=3cm,
                         overlap=2.5cm]
\end{venndiagram3sets}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Extra notes:

- I did have to manually play with the overlap and radius numbers to get a good fit for the text.
- You can pass options to `tikzpicture` with the `venndiagram3sets` option `tikzoptions`.
- Although you can change the color, I think you cannot set separate colors for separate sets.