# How to change fill opacity without affecting the angle label?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there an easy way to change the fill opacity of the sector without changing the opacity of the angle label?

I tried to use `fill opacity=0.5` but the label (`"$\alpha$"`) changes too.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0.4,-0.5) -- (0.4,0.8); % a line to show if opacity works
    \draw coordinate (a) at (3,-1);
    \draw coordinate (b) at (0,0);
    \draw coordinate (c) at (1,1);
    \draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) pic ["$\alpha$",draw=orange,fill=orange!50,fill opacity=0.5,angle radius=1cm] {angle=a--b--c};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tikz distinguishes between `fill opacity` and `text opacity`. If not both are set, defining `fill opacity` overrides the setting for `text opacity`. If you set `text opacity=1` you'll get:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0.4,-0.5) -- (0.4,0.8); % a line to show if opacity works
    \draw coordinate (a) at (3,-1);
    \draw coordinate (b) at (0,0);
    \draw coordinate (c) at (1,1);
    \draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) pic ["$\alpha$",draw=orange,fill=orange!50,fill opacity=0.5, text opacity=1,angle radius=1cm] {angle=a--b--c};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add options for the label itself using the syntax

```
"some text" {<options for the label>}, <other options>
```

hence `pic ["$\alpha$" opacity=1,draw=orange,fill=orange!50,fill opacity=0.5,angle radius=1cm] {angle=a--b--c}` gives you the desired effect. Note no comma after `" ... "`.  The braces aren't needed in this specific case because there is only one option, `opacity`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0.4,-0.5) -- (0.4,0.8); % a line to show if opacity works
    \draw coordinate (a) at (3,-1);
    \draw coordinate (b) at (0,0);
    \draw coordinate (c) at (1,1);
    \draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) pic ["$\alpha$" opacity=1,draw=orange,fill=orange!50,fill opacity=0.5,angle radius=1cm] {angle=a--b--c};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]