# How to scale an angle's label with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-angles

I would like to be able to scale the label of this angle:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Declare Points
\coordinate (X) at (6,1);
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (Y) at (3,5);

% Draw Angle
\draw[thick] (X) -- (A) -- (Y)
pic ["\ang{38}", draw, thick, angle eccentricity=1.8] {angle = X--A--Y};

% Label Points
\draw (A) node[below left, scale=0.85] {A};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Unsatisfying workaround

Drawing `"{\small \ang{38}}"` kind of "works", but I'd prefer to *scale* the label (like the other elements, for instance the vertex' name).

### Failed attempt #1

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305529/81138) gave me the idea to try `pic ["\ang{38}", draw, thick, angle eccentricity=1.8, text scale=0.85] {angle = X--A--Y};`, but `text scale` doesn't seem to exist,  because I get:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/text scale', to which you
 passed '0.85', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.17 ...ck, angle eccentricity=1.8, text scale=0.85]
                                                   {angle = X--A--Y};
```

### Failed attempt #2

From [there](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/angles-quotes/) I've found this:

> You can use a simple string “text” or a string with options, such as
>   node["text" {red, draw, thick}] to achieve an effect like
>   node[label={[red,draw,thick]text}] with less writing and more
>   readability.

But then, in order to simply test the color, as a start, writing `pic [node["\ang{38}" {red}], draw, thick, angle eccentricity=1.8] {angle = X--A--Y};` leads to:

```
\xparse function is not expandable 
l.17 pic [node["\ang{38}" {red}]
                              , draw, thick, angle eccentricity=1.8] {angle ...
```

And the less readable way also gives an error.

### Question

Is there a way I can use this advice, or any other mean, to *scale* the angle's label?

Comment: `font=\small` ?

Comment: Hum, wouldn't this be quite the same as the unsatisfying workaround?

Comment: Most likely I did not understand what you are asking. I thought "but I'd prefer to scale the label (like the other elements, for instance the vertex' name" means you want to make *all* text smaller.

Comment: Oh, you mean instead of using a scale of 0.85 for the vertex, just do not scale anything and change the font size of the whole picture?

Comment: If you want to decrease the font size of the whole `tikzpicture` (that is for *every* text that appears inside), just put the relating command `\small` or `\footnotesize` or whatever directly behind `\begin{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Put `[font=\small]` either behind `{tikzpicture}` or use with `scopes`.

Comment: Well you're right this actually provides a satisfying solution. Now I feel this is a stupid question but I couldn't have thought of this (I was thinking a bit like "the other way round").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"\ang{38}"scale=0.5`.

In general with the `quotes` syntax, `"label text" {<options for label node>}, <other stuff>`. If you only have one option, the braces aren't required.

[image: smaller label]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Declare Points
\coordinate (X) at (6,1);
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (Y) at (3,5);

% Draw Angle
\draw[thick] (X) -- (A) -- (Y)
pic ["\ang{38}"scale=0.5, draw, thick, angle eccentricity=1.8] {angle = X--A--Y};

% Label Points
\draw (A) node[below left, scale=0.85] {A};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess this answers the question you asked, though it seems from the comments that might have been the wrong question.

Comment: Yet your answer is correct and may be useful in other cases I am currently meeting! I thought this was just not possible, but it is. In the same time, for the present case, the solution given in comments will probably make it even easier.