# How to apply a clipping mask with TikZ

Tags: transparency, path-clipping, venn-diagrams, clip

Without rewriting the code, I want the part where the circles overlap to be transparent so it appears white (or whatever colour is hiding behind the circles).

Graphic designers might refer to this as a [clipping mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_path), [alpha compositing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing), etc.
It's a boolean operation: A XOR B.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3.50em, auto]

%%% define shapes %%%
\tikzstyle{bluecircle} = [draw, circle,
                          fill=blue!20,
                          line width=0.00em, 
                          minimum height=5.00em,
                          text centered]

\tikzstyle{emptycircle} = [draw, circle,
                           fill=none,
                           line width=0.10em,
                           minimum height=5.00em,
                           text centered]

\tikzstyle{emptysquare} = [draw, rectangle,
                           fill=none,
                           line width=0.10em,
                           minimum height=6.00em,
                           text width = 9.00em,
                           text centered]

%%% circle fill %%%   
\node[bluecircle]             (A) {};
\node[bluecircle, right of=A] (B) {};

%%% circle edge %%%    
\node[emptycircle]             (A2) {$A$};
\node[emptycircle, right of=A] (B2) {$B$};

%%% square edge %%%    
\node[emptysquare, xshift=1.75em] (U) {};

\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use venndiagram package. Please see [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385128/label-intersection-of-3-sets).

Comment: If you draw the circles with paths instead of nodes, you can fill the paths according to the `even odd rule`. Search for that in the manual and I think you’ll find what you’re looking for.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang It has to be nodes. Although the nodes do technically draw paths, and it's the paths that need clipping. Surely it's possible. I can't seem to figure it out though.

Answer (score 3):

Using `clip` command, the following result can be obtained.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3.50em, auto]

%%% define shapes %%%
\tikzstyle{bluecircle} = [draw, circle,
                          fill=blue!20,
                          line width=0.00em, 
                          minimum height=5.00em,
                          text centered]

\tikzstyle{emptycircle} = [draw, circle,
                           fill=none,
                           line width=0.10em,
                           minimum height=5.00em,
                           text centered]

\tikzstyle{emptysquare} = [draw, rectangle,
                           fill=none,
                           line width=0.10em,
                           minimum height=6.00em,
                           text width = 9.00em,
                           text centered]

%%% circle fill %%%   
\node[bluecircle]             (A) {};
\node[bluecircle, right of=A] (B) {};

%%% circle edge %%%    
%\node[emptycircle]             (A2) {};
%\node[emptycircle, right of=A] (B2) {$B$};

%%% square edge %%%    
\node[emptysquare, xshift=1.75em] (U) {};

\begin{scope}
        \clip (A.center) circle [radius=2.5em];
        \fill[fill=white] (B.center) circle [radius=2.5em];
    \end{scope}
%%% circle edge %%%     
\node[emptycircle]             (A2) {$A$};
\node[emptycircle, right of=A] (B2) {$B$};

\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]