# Venn diagram for a complement set

Tags: venn-diagrams

Using Venn diagrams, represent the following sets,

1. A∪(B∩C).
2. A'∩(B∪C).
3. A∩(B∪C').
   ' represents the complement of a set.

For the first I have the following code,

```
\begin{venndiagram3sets}[labelA= ,labelB= , labelC= ,radius=2cm, overlap=2cm]%
\setkeys{venn}{shade=OliveDrab!40}
\fillBCapC
\fillA
\setpostvennhook
{%
\draw (labelA) ++(-120:1.8cm) node{$ A$};
 \draw (labelB) ++(-60:1.8cm) node{$B$};
 \draw (labelC) ++(90:1.2cm) node{$C$};
\draw (labelABC) ++(90:0.1cm) node{$A\cap B\cap C$}; 
}%

\end{venndiagram3sets}
```

and it gives me the following code, which is fine
[image]

But I don't know how to fill in the others following that code, they could help me. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @CampanIgnis Hi. I think that the question of the new user is related to the package venndiagram v1.2 of Nicola L. C. Talbot, with the date 2018-06-07. https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/venndiagram/venndiagram.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [example](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/venn/) might help You:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[blend group = soft light]
    \fill[red!30!white]   ( 90:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[green!30!white] (210:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[blue!30!white]  (330:1.2) circle (2);
  \end{scope}
  \node at ( 90:2)    {Typography};
  \node at ( 210:2)   {Design};
  \node at ( 330:2)   {Coding};
  \node [font=\Large] {\LaTeX};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**[One more](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26096/tikz-labelling-venn-diagram)  with text**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{venn circle/.style={draw,circle,minimum 
   width=6cm,fill=#1,opacity=0.4}}

  \node [venn circle = red] (A) at (0,0) {$A$};
  \node [venn circle = blue] (B) at (60:4cm) {$B$};
  \node [venn circle = green] (C) at (0:4cm) {$C$};
  \node[left] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,B=1/2 ) {$A \cap B$}; 
  \node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,C=1/2 ) {$A \cap C$};   
  \node[right] at (barycentric cs:B=1/2,C=1/2 ) {$B \cap C$};   
  \node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/3,B=1/3,C=1/3 ){$A \cap B \cap C$};
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]